# Application is unable to connect to Apache ignite 2.12 after couple of days

Tags: ignite, gridgain

We are using Apache Ignite 2.12 and everything works fine but few days after unable to connect/query the cache.
Below is the exception in the logs.

> responseMessage: "**Failed to execute map query on remote node** [nodeId=16a76bdb-40bd-4a9c-8df5-dcbb989cfa21, errMsg=Getting affinity for too old topology version that is already out of history [locNode=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=16a76bdb-40bd-4a9c-8df5-dcbb989cfa21, consistentId=bcd6db5d-54da-4016-a185-b130e209fb43, addrs=ArrayList [10.15.150.17, 127.0.0.1], sockAddrs=HashSet [ig1la2pi7ac-2.ig1la2pi7ac.ig1la2pi7ac.svc.cluster.local/10.15.150.17:47500, /127.0.0.1:47500], discPort=47500, order=3, intOrder=3, lastExchangeTime=1667835848088, loc=true, ver=2.12.0#20220108-sha1:b1289f75, isClient=false], grp=FICO-PTO-TENANT-design.Hotlist-Service.HotlistCache, topVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=24, minorTopVer=6], lastAffChangeTopVer=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=24, minorTopVer=6], head=AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=40, minorTopVer=0], history=[AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=25, minorTopVer=2], AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=26, minorTopVer=0], AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=27, minorTopVer=0], AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=28, minorTopVer=0], AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=29, minorTopVer=0], AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=30, minorTopVer=0], AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=31, minorTopVer=0], AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=32, minorTopVer=0], AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=33, minorTopVer=0], AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=34, minorTopVer=0], AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=35, minorTopVer=0], AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=36, minorTopVer=0], AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=37, minorTopVer=0], AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=38, minorTopVer=0], AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=39, minorTopVer=0], AffinityTopologyVersion [topVer=40, minorTopVer=0]]]]"

Restarting the ignite pods is fixing the issue.

Comment: Do you see any "Failed to wait for partition map exchange" messages in the logs?

Comment: @IgorBelyakov yes we see this error in some.